# Declaring types for mixin class

Tags: typescript

Not a TypeScript user, but I'm writing a TypeScript declaration file for my JavaScript library, and I'm stuck on the following code:

```
function ArrayMixin(Base) {
  class ExtendedArray extends Base {}
  return ExtendedArray;
}
```

This returns a class that extends a given class. In this case I'd like to limit the Base to Arrays and TypedArrays (so-called indexed collections). I can create a union type declaring all the necessary constructors and use it as type in the function signature:

```
type IndexedCollection = ArrayConstructor|Int8ArrayConstructor
declare function ArrayMixin(Base: IndexedCollection): ExtendedArray
```

But how do I specify that my ExtendedArray extends any of those in IndexedCollection? How do I declare ExtendedArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Researching more into generics, as Søren D. Ptæus suggested, led me to the following.
In order to declare this JavaScript construction:

```
function ArrayMixin(Base) {
  class ExtendedArray extends Base {}
  return ExtendedArray;
}
```

We need this in the declaration file:

```
export declare class ExtendedArray {}

interface Constructor<T> {
    new (...args): T;
}

export declare function ArrayMixin<T extends IndexedCollection>(Base?: Constructor<T>):
 Constructor<T & ExtendedArray>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to specify that your return type extends `IndexedCollection` like this:

```
declare function ArrayMixin<T extends IndexedCollection>(Base: IndexedCollection): T
```

Comment: Thanks! This might be a naive question, but what do I do with the class itself, how should I declare it now?